# Show two vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

[image]

So I need help with this problem! I am confused because there is only one equation? I tried writing it in form $af(x) + bg(x) = 0$ but I really am quite stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: What **two** vectors??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights:

Suppose not. Then there exists $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;e^{kix}\in \text{span}\,\{1,e^{ix},e^{2ix},...,e^{(k-1)ix}\}\;$ (why?), but then:

$$(**)\;\;\;\;e^{kix}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_ne^{nix}\;,\;\;a_n\in\Bbb C\implies$$

$$0=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}e^{kix}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_n\int\limits_0^{2\pi}e^{nix}dx=2\pi a_0\implies a_0=0$$

So the sum in (**) above begins with $\;n=1\;$ . Now factor out  $\;e^{ix}\;$ in that sum and ...

Comment: so we factor out $e^{ix}$ and get $e^{kix}=e^{ix}*(a_1+a_2e^{ix}+...+a_{k-1}e^{(k-2)ix})$. What does this tell us?

Comment: Well, $\;e^{ix}\neq 0\;$ , so you have again an expression similar to the first one...go on!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{-n},a_{-n+1},\ldots, a_n\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$a_{-n}e^{-inx}+a_{-n+1}e^{(-n+1)ix}+\cdots+a_ne^{inx}=0\tag1$$
and to prove that $a_p=0$ we multiply $(1)$ by $e^{-ipx}$ and we integrate using the hint.